# How can I identify processes ROS nodelets are running in?

Tags: ros, pid, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to get the process ID of the process a ROS nodelet is running in (preferably by ROS nodelet name)? This question relates to this quiestion about [how to get the process id of a ROS node](https://answers.ros.org/question/271776/how-can-i-identify-ros-node-processes/).

With `pgrep` one can get a list of pids of nodelets if they are running in separate processes but cannot determine which pid corresponds to which nodelet:

```
pgrep nodelet
1269
1326
1555
1559
1563
1592
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271777/how-can-i-identify-processes-ros-nodelets-are-running-in?/) by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 468 on 2017-09-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you can do this by using the [Master API](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Master_API) to retrieve the list of service servers (using `getSystemState(..)`) and then filtering that list by looking for all providers of any of the typical Nodelet `manager` services ([docs](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/nodelet/html/index-msg.html)).

After you have that list, you could use the same approach as in #q271776 to get their PIDs.

To figure out which nodelets are running in which specific `manager`s, you should be able to just ask the node by invoking the `list` service and looking at the result.

As in #q271776, the `rosgraph`, `rosnode` and `rosservice` libraries can help, but most of it is XMLRPC, so could be done without any ROS dependency. Invoking the service might be harder without any ROS, but not undoable.

---

Edit: perhaps the `lookupService(..)` could also be used, but I'm not sure whether the documentation for that is correct:

> Lookup all provider of a particular service.

this suggests that *all* provider(s) will be returned, but the return type docs say this:

> (code, statusMessage, serviceUrl)
>
> service URL is provides address and port of the service. Fails if there is no provider.

So that implies only a single `serviceUrl` will be returned.

---

Edit: `rosservice find <service-type>` does something similar, so you could probably take a look at that.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2017-09-30**:
Thanks a lot. I will try to get a ROS dependent implementation running and refactor to an implementation without ROS dependency later.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-09**:
Question answered ? :)

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-02-09**:
Yepp... :)